# Express the fixed field of a subgroup $H$ of $\Gamma(L:K)$ in terms of a basis of $L$ over $K$.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I've been trying to solve this problem for $L:K$ finite with char $K = 0$:

$\beta_1,...,\beta_n$ basis for $L$ over $K$, $H$ subgroup of $\Gamma(L:K)$ $\implies$ $\phi(H) = K(\gamma_1,...,\gamma_n)$, where $\gamma_i = \sum_{\sigma \in H} \sigma(\beta_i)$

Note that $L:K$ is finite but not necessarily normal.

I think I am close because I can show that

$\Gamma(L:\phi(H)) = \Gamma(L:K(\gamma_1,...,\gamma_n))$

But does this necessarily imply $\phi(H) = K(\gamma_1,...,\gamma_n)$, given the conditions in the problem?

If I could show $L:K(\gamma_1,...,\gamma_n)$ normal, the result would follow.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I worked out the problem. I was making it too complicated by going through $\Gamma(L:\phi(H)).$  Instead I look at the fixed field $\phi(H)$ directly.

I'll post my answer here, and maybe people can check it.

For each $\tau \in H, \tau(\gamma_i) = \tau(\sum_{\sigma \in H}\sigma(\beta_i)) = \sum_{\sigma \in H}\tau\sigma(\beta_i) = \sum_{\sigma \in H}\sigma(\beta_i) = \gamma_i, 1 \le i \le n.$
So $\gamma_i \in \phi(H), 1 \le i \le n$. Thus $K(\gamma_1,...,\gamma_n) \subseteq \phi(H).$

On the other hand, consider $\alpha \in \phi(H)$. For each $\sigma \in H, \sigma(\alpha) = \alpha$. Write $\alpha = k_1\beta_1 + \dots + k_n\beta_n$. Then
$\begin{align}
\textstyle{\sum_{\sigma \in H}\sigma(\alpha)} &= \textstyle{\sum_{\sigma \in H}\sigma(k_1\beta_1 + \dots + k_n\beta_n)} \\
&= \textstyle{k_1 \sum_{\sigma \in H}\sigma(\beta_1) + \cdots + k_n \sum_{\sigma \in H}\sigma(\beta_n)} \\
&= k_1\gamma_1 + \cdots + k_n\gamma_n
\end{align}$
Also
$\sum_{\sigma \in H}\sigma(\alpha) = \sum_{\sigma \in H}\alpha = |H|\alpha$
So $\alpha = \cfrac{1}{|H|}(k_1\gamma_1 + \cdots + k_n\gamma_n) \in K(\gamma_1,...,\gamma_n).$ Thus $\phi(H) \subseteq K(\gamma_1,...,\gamma_n).$